# pycharm - can't attach to process

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I  have issues with attaching to process on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Python 2.7.15rc1. I set up system:

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

When I'm trying attach to process I get timeout error (I can see Connection to Python debugger failed: Accept timed out in event log)

```
Attaching to a process with PID=10619
/home/t/Desktop/venv/bin/python /home/t/pycharm-professional-2018.3.4/pycharm- 
2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py --port 39311 --pid 10619
```

Process finished with exit code 0
Server stopped.

I tried to attach to process using liclipse and it worked.

Comment: Sounds similar to the known PyCharm issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30064 Should be fixed in 2019.1 version, but the fix is not yet included in the EAP builds, it's on the review right now.

Comment: @PavelKarateev seems you are right

Answer (score 0):

Edit

> pycharm-professional-2018.3.4/pycharm- 
>   2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py

And enable debugging by setting `how_debug_info_on_target_process = 1`

Most probably you need to set the ptrace level, in my case the gdb was too old and didn't have `--nh` (no `~/.gdbinit`)